# TestNG 6.10+ issue with parameters tag in xml

Tags: xml, testng

To share common parameters between test suites, we are using below approach.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY parent SYSTEM "src/test/resources/<project_name>/common/parameters.xml">
    <!ENTITY host SYSTEM "src/test/resources/<project_name>/common/hostParameters.xml">
    <!ENTITY agent SYSTEM "src/test/resources/<project_name>/common/agentParameters.xml">
    ] >
<suite name="Test Suite" parallel="false" verbose="10">

  <!-- Reference to common parameters -->
  <parameters>&parent;</parameters>
  <parameters>&host;</parameters>
  <parameters>&agent;</parameters>
```

It is working with TestNG version 6.9.9 if we update TestNG with version 6.10+ we are getting below error.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 15; Element type "parameters" must be declared.

Is something changed in 6.10+ that is not allowing "parameters" element in TestNG xml? Not sure what is causing it.

Looks like lot of people do use this way, to share common parameters between different TestNG suites.
https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/sharing-parameters-among-different-testng-suites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before 6.10+, TestNG didn't check well bad formatted xml.

Your xml is wrong because you have `<parameters>` instead of `<parameter>`.
Check the DTD order to know what is possible to do: http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php

Comment: Looks like in tesng-1.0.dtd.php they do have "parameters" at start   <ul>
<li> <b>parameters</b>, which override the suite parameters    
<li> <b>groups</b>, made of two parts                          
<li> <b>classes</b>, defining which classes are going to be part
  of this test run                                   
</ul>

Comment: Nope: `<!ELEMENT suite (groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors|suite-files)*) >`

Comment: can we add "parameters" to TestNG DTD? Its valid xml entity

Comment: No, you can't modify the DTD because it is the expected format by TestNG. But you can provide your own format parser if you want.

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/YamlParser.java

Comment: @juherr I still don't get it. Where exactly in the suite file can I declare the <parameters> tag in order to re-use parameters/values from a different file?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the parameters tag. it worked.

```
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
<parameter name="url" value="http://www.google.com"/>
<parameter name="node" value="http://192.168.1.7:4444/wd/hub"/>
```